# zend framework FlashMessenger problem

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am using FlashMessenger helper to set messages, but i am unable to retrieve messages using getMessages() method. it returns null. here is my sample code:

```
<?php
class Admin_TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_flashMessenger = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
        $this->initView();
    }

    public function myAction()
    {
        $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage('test message');

        $this->_helper->Redirector("mynextrequest");
    }

    public function mynextrequestAction()
    {
        zend_debug::dump($this->_flashMessenger->getMessages());
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess "zend_debug" with small caps is not problem, or is it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i upgrade from php 5.2.0 to 5.2.9 and the problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem you need to edit library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/FlashMessenger.php
find the line:

 `self::$_session->{$this->_namespace}[] = $message;` 

and change it to

`//self::$_session->{$this->_namespace}[] = $message;

$sessionMessages = self::$_session->{$this->_namespace};

$sessionMessages[] = $message;

self::$_session->{$this->_namespace} = $sessionMessages;`



This issue only affects php 5.2 and so they have decided not to fix it and instead suggest upgrading the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

aside from the function/classname capitalization issues, make sure your Zend_Session is set up, started, and has a storage method that works.  It will use your session storage method that comes from a `new Zend_Session_Namespace('FlashMessenger')`

Answer (score 0):

There are PHP 5.2.x Versions, that have a problem with

> // Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::addMessage() (line 143)
>   self::$_session->{$this->_namespace}[] = $message;

Upgrading PHP would be a solution (as you did) or replacing the above line with the following code:

> $messages = self::$_session->{$this->_namespace};
>
> $messages[] = $message;
>
> self::$_session->{$this->_namespace} = $messages;

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that came from having **two ajax calls** that used the flashMessenger and were finishing loading in **random** order. So the first ajax call was sometimes loaded first and thus using the messages and left none for the second; and I was expecting the error messages in the second ajax call and wondered why do they show just approx 50% of the cases.