# Zend Framework - Flashmessenger - Only one character

Tags: zend-framework, flash-message

I have a little problem with FlashMessenger. When I want to retrieve the messages in my layout, it writes the first letter of the message... example "test" displays "t".

I tried a solution posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086075/zend-framework-flashmessenger-problem), but nothing changed for me.

I use php 5.3.6

Here is my code:

- In my method :

  ```
  $message = 'test';
  $this->_helper->FlashMessenger($message);
  ```
- Call in the Layout

  ```
  <div id="message_box">
      <?php echo $this->flashMessages(); ?>
  </div>
  ```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770434/zend-flashmessenger-cant-find-plugin/7774996#7774996? Anyway, my answer to that will solve your problem.

Comment: It's not the same problem, I've not an error like you, but thank you =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

In controller:

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger->addMessage("Your message", 'actions');

// you can redirect to another controller ...


$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages('actions');
```

In phtml file:

```
 <!-- some html code -->

<div id="message_box">
     <?php echo $this->messages[0]; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How the flash messages can be accessed in view instead of controller?
I do not want to use this "$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages('actions');" in controller.