# Why is Zend's FlashMessenger getMessages method not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend 1.12 and php 5.4.3 and flashMessenger->getMessages() has suddenly stopped working in a controller action.

In AController, a certain type of account is created and it takes 9 steps to create it, so I have 9 actions create1-9Action

On each step I pass the form data to the next step using flashmessenger.
This is the typical structure of an action:

```
public function create5Action()
{
  $form = new My_Form();
  $messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
  $data = $messages[0];
  if ($this->_request->isPost())
  {
    if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
    {
       /* form treatment */

      $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($data);
      $this->_redirect($this->_helper->url("create6", "A", null)); // redirect to next step
    }
  }

  $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($data);
  $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

In this action (create5) the data is intact when arriving from create4Action, it is intact when adding it as a message before `$this->view->form = $form;`, but when I add new elements to the form and submit it, `$messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();` is null and I do not know why, since it is working for all other actions.

Comment: This is not really what the flash messenger is for, you should create a session namespace object and use that

Comment: How to use FlashM. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520473/949273

Comment: I was not using namespaces since the beginning, that was it, and flashmessenger isn't really working like I wanted. Zend_Session_Namespace seems more adapted.

I actually tried to add messages with a namespace, it didn't work, I saw the question you posted already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have missed adding the `else` in the `isPost()` loop.

```
public function create5Action()
{
  $form = new My_Form();
  $messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
  $data = $messages[0];
  if ($this->_request->isPost())
  {
    if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
    {
       /* form treatment */

      $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($data);
      $this->_redirect($this->_helper->url("create6", "A", null)); // redirect to next step
    }
  } else {

      $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($data);
      $this->view->form = $form;
    }
}
```

However this is not the anticipated use of the flash messenger. I think a part of your problem is that every time a request is made the flash messenger namespace is cleared during the `postDispatch()` portion of the dispatch loop.

You may be better off using your own [Zend_Session_Namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html) instance instead of relying on the instance that flash messenger is using.

```
public function create5Action()
    {
      $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('data');//set elsewhere and forwarded and can be persistent
      $form = new My_Form();     
      $data = $session->data;
      if ($this->_request->isPost())
      {
        if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
        {
           /* form treatment */

          $session->newData = $newData;//forward data if needed, old data will persist as you require
          $this->_redirect($this->_helper->url("create6", "A", null)); // redirect to next step
        }
      } else {
          $this->view->form = $form;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I modify $session->data directly, like `$session->data["newData"] =  $newData`, it will modify the data in Zend_Session_Namespace automatically ?

Comment: actually you would use it $session->data = ''; $session->newData = ''; the $session already refers to the 'data' namespace. You can add/remove change keys as you need to. You can save strings, arrays or objects.

Comment: Thanks that worked for now. The else  isn't really required since i do not do anything if request is post and the form is not validated, it should be in the same if condition actually. And if the form is valid, i redirect to another controller, so the else is always what is under the if

Comment: Typically the work flow in ZF actions would test for ifPost() = true do isValid() else display form and accept data for a post event. The same would be true for isValid(), often we would redisplay the form and populate it if !isValid(). However I'm glad you got it working.